# Showing a sequence of integrals converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, lebesgue-integral

I'm having trouble with this problem - I don't even know how to begin.
Thoughts? Solutions with explanation? Please help!

Let $f$ be a bounded continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(t)}{1+n^2t^2}dt = f(0).$$

Comment: this question is answered here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997709/integral-of-bounded-continuous-function-on-r/997741#997741

Comment: Thanks for your response, though I have a question.

The integral I'm asking for is slightly different. It's being multiplied by n, which is approaching infinity. Does that affect your argument?

Comment: the $n$ is necessary because you want $\frac{n}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{dt}{1+n^2t^2}dt = 1$ if you make the substitution $x=nt$ in $\frac{n}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(t)}{1+n^2t^2}dt $ you will see that the $n$ cancels and shows up only as a scaling factor in $\frac1{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(\frac{x}{n})}{1+x^2}dx $